# Vue and firebase Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read a Firestore database on my Vue app by this code:

```
mounted() {
    db.collection("tete-est")
      .doc("inqueritos")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.inquerito.push({
              codigo: doc.data().a_codAgr,
              data: doc.data().a_data,
              inquiridor: doc.data().a_nomeInq,
              nome: doc.data().c1_nomeChefe
            });
        });
      });

  },
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function
[enter image description here][1]
```

My database looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: What exactly do you want to read? All the documents in the `inqueritos` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot of your database, `inqueritos` is a (root) collection and `tete-est` is your Firebase Project name.

So if you want to query all the documents in the `inqueritos` collection, you should do as follows:

```
mounted() {
    db.collection("inqueritos")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.inquerito.push({
              codigo: doc.data().a_codAgr,
              data: doc.data().a_data,
              inquiridor: doc.data().a_nomeInq,
              nome: doc.data().c1_nomeChefe
            });
        });
      });

  },
```

Comment: @DelEvil maybe upvote the answer then? And maybe also accept it as well. This is the way to thanks on StackExchange sites (StackOverflow is one one them). https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `onSnapshot` on a document reference,  `forEach` method is available on `querySnapshot` which is the result of querying on a collection reference.

Take a look at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection

You will find the answer :)